USB mouse with horizontal scrolling
I had two old Logitech-built mice, which eventually needed to be replaced as the buttons were going bad. One was an RX250, the other was an OEM product for Fujitsu-Siemens.
Both were USB mice with support for horizontal scrolling by pushing the wheel to the side. Windows support for that feature is kind of patchy but it works well on Linux. Both mice were rather basic models, comparable to those in the price range below € 20.
I am looking for a suitable replacement but I can no longer find any mouse with horizontal scrolling. Are there still any USB mice on the market that support this, preferably Logitech, and preferably in the sub-€ 20 price range? Or any mice at all?

Also to clarify, you don't want a second scroll wheel or an omnidirectional scroll wheel? For example, the MX Master has a horizontal scroll wheel you can move with your thumb.

@JMY1000 Above all, I want horizontal scrolling, and it should be similar in accessibility to vertical scrolling. So a second wheel would be fine. So would an omnidirectional wheel, as long as I can still scroll in the four cardinal directions (not, say, north-north-west when I really want to scroll north). My main point against the MX Master is that it costs 5–10 times what the RX250 would have cost (I have just edited my question to include price).

What country are you located in? I see used first-gen MX Masters for about $20, but I'm not sure if the market is that good where you are.

I'm using the Logitech G502 SE Hero and it is an excellent mouse with support of the mouse wheel horizontal scrolling.



Technically that would fulfill my requirement for horizontal scrolling, except that I would replace a bread-and-butter mouse with a killer mouse costing roughly five times as much. Are you aware of anything in the price range of the RX250?

Try searching up the MX Master 3S, it works for both MacOS and Windows and is a great mouse overall. I've been using it for around 2 years now, and so far it's been great. It also comes with a unlocked scroll wheel, which is really helpful in many situations. There's a horizontal wheel on it as well, and its actually the only mouse with horizontal scroll on the market right now. The only downside is the price, which is about $80-90ish USD
